# Passing EnvelopeId, JobId to PowerMTA from email sent through .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mail-server, system.net.mail

My application is using System.Net.Mail to send emails that goes through PowerMTA.

PowerMTA provides EnvId and JobId fields in their delivery report which I want to take advantage of for our internal reporting purpose.

Anyone knows how can I pass those values to PowerMTA from .NET.

I tried adding custom headers like  `mailObject.Headers.Add("EnvId", "MyEnvId")` but EnvId is still empty in the PMTA log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1: Configure these PowerMTA setting to true

- process-x-envid
- process-x-job

2: From .NET call add these as custom Headers:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Headers.Add("x-envid", "MyEnvId");
mail.Headers.Add("x-job", "MyJobId");
```

Note the envid or jobid values cannot have spaces else it will only display first word,